# JBoss service start failed

Tags: centos, service, jboss

I have installed JBoss Eap 6.4 through zip installation as it's written in the redhat guide, so to summarize I:

- Downloaded the zip file (eap 6.4)
- Edited the jboss-as.conf file (see image below)
- Copied the conf file into /etc/jboss-as/
- Copied jboss-as-standalone.sh into /etc/init.d
- Added the service through this command:

  > $ sudo chkconfig --add jboss-as-standalone.sh

This is my conf file:

[image]

Then I tried to start the service:

[image]

I don't know why it asks for the username, but if I type any username it doesn't do anything, it just stands by for some second and then I get a timeout:

[image]

**EDIT**
Seems like the problem it's that I have few RAM:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the contents of server.log file (or console.log)??

Comment: @alphamikevictor I didn't check the log file. It turned out to be that I had few RAM; since I'm running CentOS from virtual box I just allocated more memory to it (from 1GB to 2GB) and now I successfully started JBoss.

Comment: Glad you found the solution :)